# Bluetooth: Low Link Quality

Tags: networking, drivers, sound, bluetooth

I've just bought a USB bluetooth 5.0 adapter with RTL8761B chipset. Unfortunately the connection is not very reliable. The dongle was advertised as having 20m range. I've got approx 4-5m in the best case. I could accept it, but I've noticed that the reported connection parameters are terrible at first site even at a distance of less than 0.5m!
Bleuman-manager reports:

- Received Signal Strength: 40% (optimal)
- Link Quality: 10%
- Transmit Power Level: 50% (optimal)

These values does not change at the distance where the communication problems appear.

I am really wondering about the low Link Quality. Is there any way through which the parameters of the bluetooth transceiver can be tuned? The terrible link quality in close proximity indicates that something is not set up well.

I've used the firmware binaries from [here](https://github.com/linuxonly1993/rtl8761b_bt_5_linux).

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: @brauliobo no. I gave up.